# Convention for R function to read a file and return a collection of objects

Tags: r

I would like to find out what the "R way" would be to let users the following with R: I have a file that can contain the data of one or more analysis runs of some other software. My R package should provide additional ways to calculate statistics or produce plots for those analyses. So the first step a user would have to do, is read in the file (with one or more analyses), then select the analysis and work with it.
An analysis is uniquely identified by two names (an analysis name and an analysis type where the type should later correspond to an S3 class).

What I am not sure about is how to best represent the collection of analyses that is returned when reading in the file: should this be an object or simply a list of lists (since there are two ids for identifying an analysis, the first list could be indexed by name and the second by type). Using a list feels very low-level and clumsy though.

If the read function returns a special kind of container object what would be a good method to access one of the contained objects based on name and type?

There are probably many ways how to do this, but since I only started to work with R in a way where others should eventually use my code, I am not sure how to best follow existing R-conventions for how to design this.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not sufficiently specific. Please create a reproducible example.

Comment: @Roland: sorry it is a question about design, not sure how to include an example for this? What I would like to know is simply if there is a convention in R for retrieving objects from S3 objects by more than one criterion. If it would be just one criterion, something like obj$whatIwant would do, but is there a convention for selecting by two or more creteria similar to "whatIwant"? Solutions like nested lists feel wrong and break the OO approach.